# How to merge the images with backround using html

Tags: html

i have sliced images from given screenshot. i had put that images on my webpage using div tag. But it will show the slice cut on the edges of the images.

i need to merge my images and my background in html.

Can u please anyone help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: first at all create a fiddle or Please show your HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

1. one is you did not slice correctly otherwise
2. if you table in html means give cellspacing=0

and also if you show code in jsfiddle means easier to solve

Comment: thank u sir. but i don't have an idea where should i use this js fiddle.